# JAR Hell Issue? Weblogic 10.3.4 Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE Spring Modules Validation 0.8

Tags: spring, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, spring-3, spring-modules

I'm developing Java Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE using Maven and have been running it on Jettry server since. It works fine on Jetty.

Until we move to Weblogic 10.3.4, the trouble came. We are using Spring Modules Validation 0.8 which needs Spring 2.0.3 to run. Would this be the cause of the error? (It maybe overwrite Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE that we have)

Below are the errors

```
ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getLocalName(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Ljava/lang/String;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:375) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:280) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:131) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:147) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:100) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:298) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:241) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49) [spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) [com.bea.core.weblogic.security.identity_1.1.2.1.jar:1.1.2.1]
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) [com.bea.core.weblogic.security.wls_1.0.0.0_6-1-0-0.jar:6.1.0.0]
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1872) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68) [weblogic.jar:10.3.4.0]
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager_1.9.0.0.jar:1.9.0.0]
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager_1.9.0.0.jar:1.9.0.0]
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager_1.9.0.0.jar:1.9.0.0]

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getLocalName(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Ljava/lang/String;
at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:69) ~[spring-security-config-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1114) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1104) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:133) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:90) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:458) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:353) ~[spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
... 48 common frames omitted
```

And below are dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-rev-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        ORACLE Y U NO USE PUBLIC LICENSE FOR YOUR JDBC?
        solution, download the ojdbc6.jar on zaki's computer (the movie server)
        then run:
        mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=oracle -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
        please adjust the -Dfile location
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- diplaytag -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
        <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
        <artifactId>displaytag-export-poi</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JExcelAPI library --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- commons-lang apache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring modules validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-303 javax validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>



<build>
    <finalName>artajasa-billing</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1H.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>10000</port>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
                <scanTargets>
                    <scanTarget>target/classes/</scanTarget>
                </scanTargets>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I hope there will be 'light' this time. I've been struggling to get the answer since one week ago. Many thanks for any the help given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have conflicting version of dependencies in your `pom.xml`, Maven usually tries to use the most recent one.

However, you faced a situation when it doesn't work - `spring-modules-validation` depends on `org.springframework:spring:2.0.3`, but newer versions of Spring don't provide `org.springframework:spring` artifact anymore, therefore Maven cannot see the conflict here and doesn't exclude the older version.

So, you need to exclude it manually:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId>
    <version>0.8</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: I didn't only exclude spring artifact, but the whole spring-modules-validation artifact.
Now it works fine. Thx.